# Simple cv and python: No module named simplecv

Tags: python, module, path, simplecv

I'm new to raspberry pi and I'm trying to connect simplecv to python.
I installed simplecv on my raspberry pi using the following link: http://simplecv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/HOWTO-Install%20on%20RaspberryPi.html
and then I install svgwrite using "sudo pip install svgwrite" 
I have the simple cv working alone but when I try to import it from python I get an error that "No module named simplecv" 
When I put "which python" I get /usr/bin/python and when I put "which simplecv" I get /usr/local/bin/simplecv (I think that has something to do with my problem).